# Print in fullscreen webapp not possible (IOS9)

Tags: web-applications, printing, ios9

With IOS9 the print function does not work correctly in fullscreen mode (website pinned to homescreen with safari). When i press a print button inside a fullscreen webapp, the print dialog appears, but the print preview is not visible and the "select printer" button is always grey.

Does anyone know something about this problem?

I have tested the following page with different IPad Devices:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
        <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent" />

        <title>Demo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Demotext
        <a  href="#" onclick="window.print()">druck mich</a>
    </body>
</html>
```